# How to say "Do you still study in ABC university" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

I want to ask a friend whether she is still studying at ABC school. This is my sentence:

> ABC大学に　べんきょうしる　まだ　いる？
>
> (Do you still study at ABC University)

This that right? If not please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ABC大学でまだ勉強していますか？

or

> まだABC大学で勉強していますか？